# Smarty variable displaying through input value

Tags: php, smarty

I have a smarty variable that i want to output inside the inputs value like so

```
<input type="text"  id="video_id" name="product_data[video_id]" value="{$product_video_id}" />
```

however it does not show the value? if i move the variable outside of the input it displays?

Anything else i should be doing to get this to working in the value?

Thanks

FULL SOURCE:

```
{assign var=product_video_service value=$product_data.product_id|fn_get_product_video_service} 
{assign var=product_video_id value=$product_data.product_id|fn_get_product_video_id} 

<h2 class="subheader">{$lang.media}</h2>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="video_service">{$lang.video_service}:</label>
    <select id="video_service" name="product_data[video_service]">
        <option {if $product_video_service == 'video_service_youtube'}selected="selected"{/if} value="video_service_youtube">YouTube</option>
        <option {if $product_video_service == 'video_service_vimeo'}selected="selected"{/if} value="video_service_vimeo">Vimeo</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="video_id">{$lang.video_id}:</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text-medium" value="" maxlength="32" size="20" id="video_id" name="product_data[video_id]" value="{$product_video_id}" />
    <p><span class="small-note">&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.video_help}</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the rendered output. Showing us the source is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `value` attributes in your code, remove the first one which is empty.

```
<input type="text" class="input-text-medium" value="" maxlength="32" size="20" id="video_id" name="product_data[video_id]" value="{$product_video_id}" />
                                                ^                                                                              ^
```

Comment: opps, stupid me - how did i miss that - works fine now! thanks